# app/utils classes not found for rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a method I have added on Date that looks like this:

```
class Date
  def days_different(date)
    Float(self-date)
  end
end
```

This works great in the rest of my application, but I also have a rake task in lib/tasks/database.rake that uses this where this is not being loaded despite having the => :environment dependency on the task (greatly simplified test version shown below).

```
task :test_days_different => :environment do
  date = 2.days.ago
  puts date.days_different(DateTime.now)
end
```

Strangely, rake:test loads the helper function when it loads its environment so I'm completely baffled as to why this isn't loading in rake db

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention where you put the extended Date class but I think you have to require 'date' in the rake file.

This code snippet is not working without the require statement:

```
require 'date'
class Date
  def days_different(date)
    Float(self-date)
  end
end

date = Date.new(2001,2,1)
puts date.days_different(DateTime.now)
```

Comment: Date is loaded with rails - it seems to be more than my app/utils/date.rb extension is not loaded when running in the rake db:test_days_different context but is when running rake test or in the WEBrick dev environment.